# SharePoint Designer 2007 Workflow - Copy list items based on common field

Tags: list, designer-workflow

I have 2 lists. One is a master job tracker, the second is a job activity tracker. Jobs are assigned numbers, based on that number, if an activity is created in list 2, I want to pull certain fields from the master job tracker based off the exam number.

**List 1:**

```
 Job #             1234
 Job Name          Test Job
 Assigned to       Joe
 Rank              Captain
 Date           06/28/13
```

**List 2:**

```
Job #             1234
Job Name          (Copied from list 1)
Assigned to       (Copied from list 1)
Date              06/30/13
Etc...
```

So if I open list 2 and enter 1234 in the job number, after I save then the workflow will copy "Job name" and "Assigned to" from Job #1234 in list 1.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, rather than using the workflow to do this I would just use a lookup column in the second list that uses the Job# from list 1 as its display field.  Then you can display the Job Name and Assigned To fields along with it if you need to, but it does require a little bit of customization, apparently, SharePoint 2007.

Here's a site that claims to accomplish what I've suggested:

http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.com/2010/11/sharepoint-2007-associated-lookup.html